# How to enumerate excel worksheets in NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

How can I enumerate all the excel sheets name using NPOI? As a quick workaround, I'm using the following. But I feel super guilty for doing it...

```
        try
        {

            IWorkbook Iwb;
            Iwb = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath);

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Iwb.GetSheetAt(i).SheetName);
                i++;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {//Do Nothing..
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `NumberOfSheets` property that you can use.

Comment: Thanks! 

I thought there's supposed to be a method getNumberOfSheets() (which I cannot find in NPOI). Seems like I have some confusion between NPOI and POI.


http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getNumberOfSheets()